# BeautifulSoup for online IDE?

Tags: python, htmlparse

[This guide](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implementing-web-scraping-python-beautiful-soup/) says that to extract some information from a website using requests and Beautiful soup we can use the method BeautifulSoup(request, ‘html5lib’), but it states that it will not run on an online IDE. I was wondering why that is and if there is any workaround, if one is using an online IDE. Is there a different HTML parser?

Comment: This works online perfectly nowadays

Answer (score 2):

This is now (**UPDATED**) possible via Online Idle at [Repl.it](https://repl.it/languages/python3) , [Rextester](https://rextester.com/l/python3_online_compiler). This was not possible earlier since some of the online compilers couldn't have one of those (requests, beautifulsoup, html2lib) libraries within them.

Comment: if this answers your question, mark this as the answer so that the question is closed